# How to Interpret This transaction

Tags: transactions, blockchain.info

I got lost in reading this transaction:
[a tx from blockchain.com](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/137f0e908ed1820476e6d5ecd67dbd81610359517b6194fb61dc61631f946273)

This transaction does not have an input address, instead, it says "COINBASE (Newly Generated Coins)". Is it a block reward to the miner? But the amount does not add up, since it is 6.71380828 BTC rather than 6.25.
Another address as shown here
[OP_Return with same amount](https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/16sAXi1jxhxKCfY84hubDdnFNaAhqd5t49)
This address transfers the same amount to the same address for every block (1111111111111111111114oLvT2   0.00137500 BTC) after the OP_Return mark. Since Wikipedia said OP_Return means invalid transactions and these transfers are often marked spend. I'm wondering are these valid transactions? Otherwise, how can they be spent?
Can anybody help me out in reading these two transactions? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

Yes Coinbase means it's the block reward. The block reward is the 6.25 (currently) plus the sum of the fees of all the other transactions in the block.

Comment: Thanks a lot! How about this page when all receivers are listed after OP_RETURN? The amounts were spent which should not happen when the tx was void right? https://www.blockchain.com/btc/tx/d42824ea9a2d470592506769616370eb8875f1a42bda1cb0493bc8e889af03d6

Comment: @Angel - that transaction has 4 outputs. Order of outputs is not significant. One output uses OP_RETURN to store data in the blockchain. No idea why you think the transaction is void?